# Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $f_X(x)$ can be a density function

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function

\begin{equation*} f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{4x^2}{5}               
& \text{ , if } 0 < x \leq 1\\
\alpha(5-2x)         & \text{ , if } 1 \leq x < 2\\ \beta x^2            & \text{ , if } 2 \leq x < 3\\ 0         
& \text{ , else } \end{cases} \end{equation*}

I want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a way that $f_X(x)$ can be a density function.

I tried integrating it knowing that: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) dx = 1$, and dividing it into multiple integrals and I was able to get an equation with $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But I would need another one. I know I should use somehow that $P(a \leq x \leq b) = \int_a^b f_X(x) dx$ but I don't know how am I supposed to do that. Note that if $x = 1$ then it has two corresponding conditions in $f_X(x)$.

Comment: home work? mark it with self-study tag

Comment: A single equation in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ typically will have many solutions: there's no problem with that.  However, your observation about $f(1)$ also extends to $f(2),$ ultimately giving *three* equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta:$ let's hope there does exist a solution!

Comment: @whuber: it doesn't extend to $f(2)$, as the upper bound for the second term is $<2$ and not $\leq2$. Therefore, there are just two equations and you can solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @shs Thanks--I overlooked the strict inequality.  I think you have hit on the key to a solution.  (But what a terrible exercise from a pedagogical perspective!)

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3396524/15941 where it was asked an hour earlier than the above, and where it has already received an answer too.